# Differentiate between JDBC Driver exception and Database exception

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception, error-code

This [Jdbc tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm) states the following:

> A SQLException can occur both in the driver and the database. When
>   such an exception occurs, an object of type SQLException will be
>   passed to the catch clause.

The same tutorial also states:

> getSQLState( ):   Gets the XOPEN SQLstate string. For a JDBC driver
>   error, no useful information is returned from this method. For a
>   database error, the five-digit XOPEN SQLstate code is returned. This
>   method can return null.

So it seems like a SQLException can occur in the driver and in the database.

I was looking at the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) for `SQLException` class and the [oracle jdbc tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) 
which says the following about **SQLState Code**

> A SQLState code: These codes and their respective meanings have been
>   standardized by ISO/ANSI and Open Group (X/Open), although some codes
>   have been reserved for database vendors to define for themselves. This
>   String object consists of five alphanumeric characters. Retrieve this
>   code by calling the method SQLException.getSQLState.

and about the **Error Code**

> An Error code : This is an integer value identifying the error that
>   caused the SQLException instance to be thrown. Its value and meaning
>   are implementation-specific and might be the actual error code
>   returned by the underlying data source. Retrieve the error by calling
>   the method SQLException.getErrorCode.

From the two it seems like a SQLState code would be a better candidate to differentiate between the driver and database exception.

**To differentiate between Diver exception and Database exception , would a catch clause like the following work:**

```
   catch (SQLException se) 
   {   
       if(se.getSQLState() != null) 
       {
         System.out.println("Exception occured in the database");

         System.out.println("Database's native Error Code:"+se.getErrorCode());

         try
         {
            if(conn.getMetaData().getSQLStateType() == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Open Group Error Code : "+ se.getSQLState());
            }
            else if(conn.getMetaData().getSQLStateType() == 2) 
            {
                System.out.println("SQL99 Error Code : "+ se.getSQLState());                    
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Database vendor reserved Code : "+ se.getSQLState());                   
            }
         }  
         catch (SQLException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println("Exception occured in the databse driver");

           System.out.println("Datasbe Driver Error Code:"+se.getErrorCode());
       }

       // ***  Code for cleaning up database resources would go here ***
   }
```

Comment: Well [the official tutorial says otherwise](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html): "*When JDBC encounters an error during an interaction with a data source, it throws an instance of SQLException*". So any SQLException indicates that something went wrong "with the database". From the application's point of view it doesn't really matter whether the problem was "in the driver" (whatever you think that is) or in the database.

Comment: _"For a JDBC driver error, no useful information is returned from this method."_ is simply wrong. The SQL CLI book documents a range of SQLstate codes that apply to call-level interfaces (like JDBC), and vendors and drivers are even allowed to define their own sql states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like a SQLException can occur both in the driver and in the database.

No.

Only the driver can throw an SQLException. It does so in response to an *error* produced by the database. Part of the driver's function is to map those to SQLExceptions.

You should use the [Oracle JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), not arbitrary Internet junk. What the *official* tutorial says is 'When JDBC encounters an error *during an interaction with a data source,* it throws an instance of SQLException' [my emphasis].

Comment: I am basing this on this jdbc tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm > I have also updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Your source is wrong. The database is almost certainly not written in Java, and therefore can't throw Java exceptions at all. See my edit.